# Interconnect between per-core L2 and L3 in Core i7

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

The Intel core i7 has per-core L1 and L2 caches, and a large shared L3 cache. I need to know what kind of an interconnect connects the multiple L2s to the single L3. I am a student, and need to write a rough behavioral model of the cache subsystem.
Is it a crossbar? A single bus? a ring? The references I came across mention structural details of the caches, but none of them mention what kind of on-chip interconnect exists.

Thanks,

-neha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern i7's use a ring.  From [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/sandy-bridge-core-i7-2600k-core-i5-2500k,2833-2.html):

> Earlier this year, I had the chance to talk to Sailesh Kottapalli, a
>   senior principle engineer at Intel, who explained that he’d seen
>   sustained bandwidth close to 300 GB/s from the Xeon 7500-series’ LLC,
>   enabled by the ring bus. Additionally, Intel confirmed at IDF that
>   every one of its products currently in development employs the ring
>   bus.

Your model will be very rough, but you may be able to glean more information from public information on i7 performance counters pertaining to the L3.